# An iterable implementation of LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I am curious as to what improvements to my code can be suggested.

```
package concepts;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedList<M> implements Iterable<LinkedListNode<M>> {

    public static class LinkedListIterator<O> implements Iterator<LinkedListNode<O>> {
        private LinkedListNode<O> curNode;

        public LinkedListIterator(LinkedList<O> linkedList) {
            curNode = linkedList.head;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (curNode != null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public LinkedListNode<O> next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            } else {
                LinkedListNode<O> temp = curNode;
                curNode = curNode.next;
                return temp;
            }

        }

    }

    public LinkedListNode<M> head;

    public boolean add(M newData) {
        LinkedListNode<M> newNode = new LinkedListNode<M>();
        newNode.data = newData;
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            LinkedListIterator<M> it = new LinkedListIterator<M>(this);
            LinkedListNode<M> lastNode = null;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                lastNode = it.next();
            }
            if (lastNode != null) {
                lastNode.next = newNode;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<LinkedListNode<M>> iterator() {
        return new LinkedListIterator<M>(this);
    }

}
```

Here is the LinkedListNode implementation:

```
package concepts;

public class LinkedListNode<N> {
    public N data;
    public LinkedListNode<N> next;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Antipattern**

It's not a good idea to expose the internal list nodes, and this is why:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(123);
    // Make a loop:
    list.head.next = list.head;
    int i = 0;

    for (LinkedListNode<Integer> node : list) {
        ++i;

        if (i == 100) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("i = " + i);
}
```

As the above snippet demonstrates, a user may restructure your linked list into a cycle in which iteration will never terminate. So the moral here is that:

***hide implementation from the user!***

First of all, make **`head`** a private field. Then, reimplement the iterator that iterates over **values** and not the internal nodes holding those values.

Additional field **`tail`** would not hurt, while keeping your **`add`** method a constant time operation.

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
package concepts;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedListCR<E> implements Iterable<E> {

    private static final class LinkedListNode<E> {
        private E element;
        private LinkedListNode<E> next;

        LinkedListNode(E element) {
            this.element = element;
        }
    }

    private class LinkedListIterator implements Iterator<E> {

        private LinkedListNode<E> nextNodeToReturn = head;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextNodeToReturn != null;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Iterator exceeded.");
            }

            E ret = nextNodeToReturn.element;
            nextNodeToReturn = nextNodeToReturn.next;
            return ret;
        }

    }

    private LinkedListNode<E> head;
    private LinkedListNode<E> tail;

    public void add(E element) {
        LinkedListNode<E> newnode = new LinkedListNode<>(element);

        if (head == null) {
            head = newnode;
            tail = newnode;
        } else {
            tail.next = newnode;
            tail = newnode;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new LinkedListIterator();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListCR<String> list = new LinkedListCR<>();
        list.add("hello");
        list.add("world");
        list.add("y'all");

        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.